# Estimating a probability distribution

Tags: probability, numerical-methods

During the execution of a script I wrote, the answer is a stochastic variable with an unknown distribution.

While I do not know the distribution of the answer, I do have access to the following information:

- Moments can be approximated pretty well with standard quadratures
- Random values can be evaluated very fast
- Most of the time I have a rough estimation of the support of the distribution

What would be the best approach (as in: best approximation given a fixed time bound) to finding an estimation for the probability distribution?

I could draw random values, and use the resulting histogram as an approximation, but this is slow converging.
I have not yet tried entropy maximizing algorithms, but I suppose those could work as well.

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) or orthogonal series density estimation (e.g., wavelet density estimation).

Do you know the support (non-zero domain) of the density?

Comment: As far as I see, 'kernel density estimation' is a fancy term for smoothing the curve?
That's great for displaying the result, but it doesn't decrease the absolute error compared to a normal histogram.
I was actually looking for a method to make better use of the moments (or at least a method to combine both the information of the random samples and the moments)
(but thanks for the answer anyway ;-) )

Comment: No, that's not true. Another question then is are you dealing with a discrete distribution or a continuous distribution? I assumed your histogram was made by binning but now I suspect you have a discrete distribution.

Comment: No, the output is a continuous distribution, but the approximation with sample points is (obviously) discrete.  In any way, a discrete approximation will do. I am not really looking for any nice looking smooth curves, I really just want to make better use of the information I have than just sampling the distribution (normalizing to the known moments seems to help a little)

Comment: Smoothing is not superfluous; it is done to avoid [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).